# How can I see the list of Stack Exchange sites to which I belong (my account is associated)?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

"*Welcome!  Your account has automatically been associated with 214 other Stack Exchange sites.*"

Hey, that's great ...uh... I wonder what they all are, again...?  I'd love to go run down the list and try to answer a few questions -- you know, give back to the community and all.

Is there a way to see a list of Stack Exchange sites to which my account is associated?

(I can remember Stack Overflow, and maybe a handful of the *.stackexchange.com sites, and I realize that I can sort of reverse engineer a partial list by looking for activity notes, etc.  Can Stack Overflow provide me with a definitive list?)

Comment: What! **214** other Stack EXchange Sites?

Answer (score 3):

> How can I see the list of stack-exchange sites to which I belong (my account is associated)?

There is a link in your user profile actually.

[image]

https://stackexchange.com/users/16124/olie?tab=accounts

And I think you don't have association with 214 other sites, and *214* might be just bug with description.

ref: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/stack-exchange-network-profiles/

Comment: I only see 7 accounts in that list. Where are the other 207?

Comment: @Gabe, I don't think he really associated 214 sites, that msg might be just bug.

Comment: Sorry, "214" was meant to be humorous.  Point being, I can't even remember 7, let alone if I join more.

Thanks!